# WSS 3.0 (Sharepoint) Internal 500 Error

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, wss-3.0

I have installed WSS 3.0 on Windows Server 2008 R2. Over the weekend the system admin installed Double Take to backup the server. During the installation process SQL Server 2008 was installed. Now when I load WSS the page is blank and on the server I get the classic "Internal 500" error. I uninstalled all the 2008 SQL Server items and tried to get the WSS site back up and running. I have verified the database is still located on the server and has my existing data. I have successfully backed this up for safety. I ran the Sharepoint Products and Technologies Configuration Wizard but no luck getting the site back up and running. I looked around the forums and didn't see this exact problem. Help....

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked that the database is still accessible by WSS and that WSS has permissions to read/write to the database.

Also have you checked your event log on the server.  This can sometimes give information about errors/issues that WSS is having when trying to access its database and failing.

Hope this helps..